# C#WPF and C++/CLI and C++ add external library error in C++/CLI

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++-cli, conan

I'm setting up [C# WPF] and [C++/CLI] and [C++ code with external library ] solution in VS 2017.

I have one VS solution with 3 projects: test_app(c++), Wrapper(C++/CLI) and Sandbox(C# WPF).

Solution is correct and work w/o adding libraries.

I am use [conan](https://conan.io) as package manager (added VS conan extension and include conanfile.txt to my test_app project.

conanfile.txt:

```
 [requires]
 boost/1.69.0@conan/stable
 websocketpp/0.8.1@bincrafters/stable
 [generators]
 visual_studio
```

c++ test_app builds w/o errors:

```
1>Done building project "test_2_aaa.vcxproj".
========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

But if I add  to my test_app/Entity.h header and compile soultion, I have error in my C++/CLI Wrapper (conan install deps and test_app rebuilds normally):

```
2>------ Rebuild All started: Project: Wrapper, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
2>stdafx.cpp
2>AssemblyInfo.cpp
2>Entity.cpp
2>c:\users\taipoxin\source\repos\test_2_aaa\test_2_aaa\entity.h(3): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'websocketpp/client.hpp': No such file or directory
2>Generating Code...
2>Done building project "Wrapper.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Maybe problems with configuring projects or linking, but I cannot get what is bad. 
I use test_app in Wrapper using header `#include "../test_2_aaa/Core.h"` in Wrapper/Entity.h

My test_app configured as **Static library (.lib)** and Wrapper configured as **Dynamic library (.dll)**

test_app is checked in Wrapper's project dependencies.

Screen with whole structure:
[solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lvfN.png)

My test_app main files:

https://gist.github.com/taipoxin/0a2e908c7e7c2ca621361a3a656830a2

My Wrapper main files:

https://gist.github.com/taipoxin/6771b9372af6c00f7eee3896638b39d8

If you have additional questions, you can ask me.

Thank you.

UPD: Also I tried add conanfile to Wrapper and install deps there, but many errors accured when I tried it.

Comment: Not familiar with conan, but for some reason apparently the include directories of the C++ library didn't traverse to the wrapper library. Maybe there's a command you can instruct conan to export an include path explicitly; if not, as a workaround, you could just add the missing include path to the wrapper library as well.

Comment: @Aconcagua maybe I should link libs to Wrapper in Visual Studio? But I dont know how.

Comment: Check `Wrapper` project properties, did you specify the static library (`test_app.lib`) in `Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies`?

Comment: @SergeyShevchenko hello, no, it doesn't work. I tried set it as you advised, with path to test_app.lib and w/o, but it does not work. Also I tried go `Wrapper -> Add->Reference->Browse` and set up it there, but VS throws error _"could not add reference to ...test_app.lib as it is not of a type or version current project can use."_

Comment: @taipoxin `test_app.lib` definitely should be specified in linker's `Additional Dependencies`. Also ensure that you have specified directory where to search for that .lib file: open Wrapper properties -> `VC++ Directories` -> `Library Directories`. There you need to specify a path to the `test_app.lib` file, something like `..\test_app\$(Configuration)`

Comment: @SergeyShevchenko I made what you advised, rebuild solution, but error still exists. In Library Directories I specified abs path to /test_app/Debug, where is test_app.lib exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made another VS solution with WPF C++/CLI and C++ libraries, by modifying WPF-C++/CLI layers.

Now it tested and published to my public github **[repository](https://github.com/taipoxin/WPF_Cpp-CLI_Cpp-libs_template) under GNU GPL v3**.

Enjoy :)